# View Source Information for Dynamic Tables

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a vb.net web project that contains some dynamically filled tables.  I recently changed how this data is calculated, and now it is not being displayed properly.  There are many web tables being nested inside of each other, and I suspect that I messed up something with how those tables are being nested.  I'm still quite new to web development, so I'm having some trouble tracking down where the issue is originating from.

I've learned that I can view the source code for my webpage while I'm debugging it in a browser by right clicking in the browser and selecting something like 'View Page Source'.  This is very helpful for visualizing how various tables are nested inside each other, and has helped me fix a couple issues already.  However, I've noticed that the dynamically created content doesn't seem to appear in this source anywhere.

For example, if I make a web table that loads usernames from a sql table and displays them, searching for a given username in the source will return 0 matches, even if I can see that username on the screen in the debug session I'm currently running.

A couple questions:

- Why does my dynamic data not show up in the source?
- Is there a way I can make it show up?
- If not, what other ways are there to examine how the different tables are nested at runtime after I've filled my tables with data?

---

UPDATE:
I did some more research, and it looks like any code that is run on the server isn't visible in that piece of source that I mentioned above.  I do have `runat="server"` set for my table, so maybe this answers my first question.  I'm still lost on the other two though - and those are probably the more important questions in terms of helping me fix my problem I'm having.

Comment: Look into using a devloper console in your browser. Chrome's is good - just right-click a control on the page and 'inspect element' or press F12 and use the magnifying glass at the top left of the console to select the area of interest. Firefox also has one, and I think modern versions of IE do too. Makes it a lot easier to investigate styling, contents, etc. and may help you locate your usernames. If they're on the page then they'll definitely be in some source code somewhere, just possibly not in an obvious place.

Comment: @DrewMorgan: Thanks, the developer console helped a ton.  I was able to use that to verify that an extra cell was getting created, and use that to track down and fix the issue that was causing my tables to appear incorrectly.  If you want to re-post your comment as an answer to my third question, I'll upvote and accept so you get the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using a devloper console in your browser. Chrome's is good - just right-click a control on the page and 'inspect element' or press F12 and use the magnifying glass at the top left of the console to select the area of interest. Firefox also has one, and I think modern versions of IE do too. Makes it a lot easier to investigate styling, contents, etc. and may help you locate your usernames. If they're on the page then they'll definitely be in some source code somewhere, just possibly not in an obvious place.